# MSBuild with MultiProcessorCompilation fails with fatal error C1905

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild

When building my project like this

`msbuild MyProject.vcxproj -p:MultiProcessorCompilation=true;CL_MPCount=8 -p:Platform=x86 -p:Configuration=release -t:Rebuild`

msbuild fails while linking with `LINK : fatal error C1905: Front end and back end not compatible (must target same processor).`

If I'm doing the same without `MultiProcessorCompilation` it builds the project fine without any errors.

`msbuild MyProject.vcxproj -p:Platform=x86 -p:Configuration=release -t:Rebuild`

Any ideas why the project isn't building with MP. Other projects i can build with MP and they are configured mostly the same.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trying everything I got it. You need to set `/p:PreferredToolArchitecture=x64`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/msbuild-visual-cpp-overview?view=msvc-160. By default its set to `x86` and it seems that the multiprocessor compilation and linking is switching while running to `x64` and this is causing this error.